# ajax и responseXML

Tags: ajax, javascript

Напишите мне пожалуйста простой пример ajax запроса с использованием XML файла с содержанием

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?>
<root>
<data>
  Это некоторые данные, которые хранятся в XML-файле
  и были получены JavaScript-ом.
</data>
<data>
  Это некоторые данные, которые хранятся в XML-файле
  и были получены JavaScript-ом.
</data>
</root>
```

Чтобы данные с первого и второго тегов `<data>` присваивались на переменные obj1 и obj2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите вот эти примеры:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/